# how to make the text go to the next line in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to build a cv app that i can present my information. but when i write a long text it can not go to next line auto and i tried other solution but it does not work. here the code

```
SingleChildScrollView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    child: Flexible(
              child: Text(
                        'longgggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg text',
                         overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                         softWrap: false,
                         style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                   fontFamily: 'NotoSans',
                                   fontSize: 15,
                                    ),
                    ),                             
            ),
),
```

here is the image
[here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hrtuj.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Simply use \n inside the text.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use`softWrap: true,` instead of `softWrap: false,` this will make the text go to the next line whenthere is no more space.

Just make sure the container where the text is, lets it go to the next line, if the height of the container is fixed it'll get the overflow error but on the vertical axis

Comment: how to make it not fixed the height of the countainer?

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way to do it is make a `container` and customize it a bit like you want for example you want border or not its up-to you. Add padding to it so the `text` inside the `container` will adjust itself automatically it wont go out of the `container`.

Comment: yeah i did it before i think but i wanted to use a different way of doing it to get better understanding